# Codeiginiter - Validate from user input and check if data exist in two tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here's the explanation:

I have one textbox for the participant id, when the user makes an input it will check on the **registered_user** table, if the user is already registered, it will do the second validation, check whether the user has done a test or not, by checking the **tpa_test** table.

after the user tests, the data will be stored in the **tpa_test** table.

I can check if the participant id is exist on **registered_user** with this code :

> Models

```php
    public function get_refid($refid)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM registered_user where refid='$refid'");
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $cek_refid = $sql->num_rows();

        if ($cek_refid > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

> Controller

```php
function get_refid_exist() {
        if (isset($_POST['refid'])) {
            $refid = $_POST['refid'];
            //print_r($refid);die;
            $results = $this->M_Ujian->get_refid($refid);
            print_r($results);
            if ($results === TRUE) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">ID Peserta salah atau tidak terdaftar</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>ID Peserta ditemukan!</strong> Silahkan klik tombol selanjutnya.</div>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">ID Peserta wajib diisi.</div>';
        }
    }
```

> And this is my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>Ujian/get_refid_exist".replace("http://", "https://"),
            data: $("#typingtestForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
              $('#msg').show();
              $("#msg").html(msg);
              if ($('#msg').text() == "ID Peserta ditemukan! Silahkan klik tombol selanjutnya.") {
                cekcookie();
                $('.sw-btn-next').prop("disabled", false);
              } else {
                $('.sw-btn-next').prop("disabled", true);
              }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              $('#msg').show();
              $("#msg").html("<div class=\"alert alert-secondary\" role=\"alert\">" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown + "<\div>");
            }
          });
```

So how can I validate the values in both tables?

If the value is in table **registered_user** and not in table **tpa_test**, the result is TRUE,

If the value is in table **registered_user** and is in table **tpa_test** the result is FALSE,

and if the value is not in tables **registered_user** and **tpa_test** then the result is FALSE,

Thank you!

Comment: both tables have same column names to add where conditions?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes, both have same column names

Comment: Your textbox is  for all users or  registered user only ? if for registered users  so you can change your logic to give access to registered users only by using in your controller  __construct

Comment: @HussamAdil for registered user only, but i want to validate it so registered user cannot run two test after they submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to write model function as follows. It returns true only when your conditions are satisfied.

```
public function get_refid($refid)
{
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM registered_user where refid='$refid'");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $cek_refid = $sql->num_rows();

    $sql1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tpa_test where refid='$refid'");
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $cek_refid1 = $sql1->num_rows();

    if ($cek_refid > 0 && $cek_refid1 == 0 ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is the query that the OP had written, but try to minimize the usage of `SELECT *` for possible performance issues. Check this answer.

Comment: @Mido He hasn't explained about schema and indexes.